# How to read/write .sit files with Python in Linux

Tags: python, file, extract

How to read/write a .sit archive using Python in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dealing with older library formats I tend to fall back on command line utilities.  You should be able to find sit manipulation tools.

As to making them, I'd suggest using an alternative format.  You probably have a specific purpose in mind, but it's a fairly outdated format and you'd be better off with ZIP or TAR.GZ.